# Abort with a string "abort" a while-loop in this simple calculator program made with scanner class and Java

Tags: java, loops, class, while-loop, abort

Please help me to abort the while loop with `sc.equals("abort")` input/n at any time in the process.

```java
  public class Calculator {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            double wert1, wert2, ergebnis;
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            boolean start = true;
            while(start) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Pleaser Enter First Number");
                    wert1 = sc.nextDouble();

                    System.out.println("please Enter a Operator +,-,/,*");
                    String operator = sc.next();

                    System.out.println("please Enter second Value");
                    wert2 = sc.nextDouble();

                    if (operator.equals("+")) {
                        ergebnis = wert1 + wert2;
                        System.out.println("Das Ergebnis ist " + ergebnis);
                    }
                    if (operator.equals("-")) {
                        ergebnis = wert1 - wert2;
                        System.out.println("Das Ergebnis ist " + ergebnis);
                    }
                    if (operator.equals("*")) {
                        ergebnis = wert1 * wert2;
                        System.out.println("Das Ergebnis ist " + ergebnis);
                    }
                    if (operator.equals("/")) {
                        ergebnis = wert1 / wert2;
                        System.out.println("Das Ergebnis ist " + ergebnis);
                    }
                    if (sc.equals("abort")) {//why doesnt this work?
                        start = false;
                        break;
                    }
                } catch (InputMismatchException e) {

                    if (sc.equals("abort")) {//why doesnt this work?
                        start = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    else{sc.nextLine();}
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Abort with a string "abort" a while-loop in this simple calculator program made with scanner class and Java.

Answer (score 0):

`sc` is the `Scanner` object, it does not represent directly what you type. You can retrieve what you type with `sc.next()`.
You already defined `String operator = sc.next()`, so just use `if (operator.equals("abort"))` instead of `if (sc.equals("abort"))`.

Comment: Yes, thanks. But I would like abort the operation immediatly
when i just add if (sc.equals("abort"))  
I have to fill out first the other queries first and only then the process then is finished

Comment: Sorry but I'm not sure I understand correctly. If you change your condition like I said, and change you catch statement to simply `start = false;`, you will stop your while loop any time you type " abort ". Isn't that what you want to do ?

Comment: Sorry tryin to do this doesnt work
added  if (operator.equals("abort"))  in the try block, and sc.nextLine();
start = false; break; in the exception tried a lot other combinations. I want to have a loop going calculating infinite only abort when the word abort is pressed doesnt work sorry

Comment: Your catch should be : `catch (InputMismatchException e) { start = false;       }`.
After the line `String operator = sc.next();`, add this :
`if (operator.equals("abort")) {break;}`.
Is it working now ?

Comment: Yes thanks a lot it is a little bit better,
now it can abort at every step. But at the first step i have to put in a double number else i get thrown out. At the next step i have to enter a operator in String and I can go only out with abort and thats fine, but also in the next step. I have to insert another double number anything else will end the process. I thought catch some other exceptions but at the double input step it wouldnt help i think because it only recognizes the mismatch exception at this step and not the string word abort maybe. i dont know, sorry. Thank you for your help